Banno API - Disable/Enable Features
I am using the Banno API and can retrieve customer information but I'm wondering if it's possible to make changes to a customer profile using the API. Can features like Bill Pay, RDC and Transfers be enabled or disabled using the API?

Can you clarify more? Do you mean like one of these? Banno Admin API - Abilities or perhaps Banno - Admin API - User Abilities?

If I login to Banno People and pull up a customer, I can toggle off the RDC, Payments, Outbound Transfers, etc. I'm wondering if that can be done through the API. I am able to retrieve information from the API but can I have it go out and enable/disable one of those features? Thanks!

It sounds like you may want to check out the Admin API Abilities endpoints. (Note: the Admin API is different from the Consumer API, see the Admin API authentication overview for getting started details.)
Specifically the PUT /a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/abilities/update endpoint will allow you to toggle abilities for a specific user like you described.
